# macbook pro question mark on start up -no harddrive?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, macos

Am having an 13" macbook pro from 2011, recently during dj-ing my software just stop working. 
After the restart I've only got the question mark sign .I've try to fix it via internet recovery  but my hard drive could not be found in disk utility at all. I've tested my hard drive on another mac book pro same as mine and it's working perfect. So does that mean is the hard drive cable, or could be even something else, and if it's so what are my options
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's the SATA Flex cable used in the MacBook Pro that has died.  I have the same laptop and it's died as well.  You can either go to the Apple Store to have it replaced for a nominal fee, or do it yourself by ordering [this part](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Early-2011-Late-2011-Hard-Drive-Cable/IF163-026-1).

Comment: hmm i think it's the SATA cable as well but am wondering is there a chance to be something else ? motherboard or else????

Comment: If you've verified that the drive works in other laptops, then yes it's likely the cable.  Like I said in my post, I had the same exact problem with mine where the laptop does not recognize the drive at all.